# Jquery getting values of slider inside .each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-mobile

I have 3 sliders (they are dynamic, so I need to loop through them).

I have a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mtait/R5czJ/

HTML is:

```
<label for="slider1">item 1</label>
<input type="range" class="mtslide" name="slider1" id="slider1" min="0" max="10" value="0">
<label for="slider2">item 2</label>
<input type="range" class="mtslide" name="slider2" id="slider2" min="0" max="10" value="0">
<label for="slider3">item 3</label>
<input type="range" class="mtslide" name="slider3" id="slider3" min="0" max="10" value="0">
```

I am trying to loop through them, and create a JSON string:

```
function slide() {

    var ExtraPrices = [20.00,30.00,50.00];
    var ExtraIDs = [1,2,3];

    var count = 0;
    var arr = [];

    $('.mtslide').each(function () {
    var obj = {
        id: ExtraIDs[count],
        price: ExtraPrices[count],
        number: $(this).slider("option", "value")
    };
    arr.push(obj);
    count += 1;
    });

    alert(JSON.stringify(arr));

}
```

However, "number" or the value of the sliders, is always null:

[image: ScreenShot]

How do I get the correct value of each slider, within my .each loop above?

thank you,

Mark

Comment: instead of `$(this).slider("option", "value")` try `$(this).attr("value")`

Comment: Try logging `$('#slider1').slider("option", "value")` outside of the `.each()`

Comment: is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/R5czJ/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's each function actually gives you two variable: index and Element
http://api.jquery.com/each/

Assuming you want the value of each element you want something like this:

```
$('.mtslide').each(function (index, Element) {
    var obj = {
        id: ExtraIDs[index],
        price: ExtraPrices[index],
        number: $(Element).val()
    };
    arr.push(obj);
});
```

Keeping a separate array for price and id can be error prone. You should consider specifying additional values on an html element with data attribute. 
http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/
http://api.jquery.com/data/
Something like this:

```
<input type="range" class="mtslide" name="slider1" id="slider1" min="0" max="10" value="0" data-price="20.00" data-id="1">
<input type="range" class="mtslide" name="slider2" id="slider2" min="0" max="10" value="0" data-price="30.00" data-id="2">
<input type="range" class="mtslide" name="slider3" id="slider3" min="0" max="10" value="0"  data-price="50.00" data-id="3">
```

Then you can call them more specifically to the element:

```
$('.mtslide').each(function (index, Element) {
    var obj = {
        id:  $(Element).data("price"),
        price: $(Element).data("price"),
        number: $(Element).val()
    };
    arr.push(obj);
});
```

The complete fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Wwwtv/2/

Comment: Hi - that still shows null I'm afraid.  I've added a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mtait/R5czJ/ - and one with your updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/mtait/Wwwtv/ - thank you

Comment: If you're looking for the element's value and slider is not a special function you want to use $(Element).val(). edited my answer

Comment: I wasn't aware you could do that @kenttam - thank you very much for your help, have a  great weekend.  Mark